# Remove/mask an IP address from the WebApi response odata.metadata

Tags: asp.net-web-api, web-config, odata, metadata

Whenever I make a call to my Api through Postman, it's returning a response containing IP Address

```
{
  "@odata.context":"http://<Ip Address>/odata/$metadata#Product","value":[

  ]
}
```

Is there a way to remove/mask the IP Address from odata.context URL through web.config file or through a minimum code change in my Web Api project

I tried several ways to implement the same like URL rewrite and proxy, but non of them worked.

Below are the config rules I tried.

```
<rule name="RemoveIpAddress">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_ODATACONTEXT}" pattern="^.*@odata\.context.*$" />
    </conditions>                   
</rule>
                
                
<rule name="HideIpAddress" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)@odata\.context" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}@odata.context" />
        </rule>
        
<rule name="RewriteODataContext" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)@odata\.context" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}@odata.context" />
        </rule>
```